# Variable value from other jQuery extend

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next code

```
$.fn.funcion01=function(){
    var section = $('#thissection').val();
}
```

I need send the variable value to the other function extend

```
$.fn.funcion02=function(){
    var section = ??
}
```

Comment: Can you say the context?

Comment: The first function can return the value, and you can call that function from the second function.

Comment: It doesn't make sense.... Why would you want do this? Can you say what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @user2694772, check my answer which has working run snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below snippet which keeps your value inside `jquery` object itself.

```js
(function($) {
 $.fn.funcion01 = function(){
     $.myConfigName = 'hello';
 }

 $.fn.funcion02 = function(){
     $.fn.funcion01();
     alert($.myConfigName);
 }
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function () {
   $.fn.funcion02();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/cfckvvzw/14/

```
<input onclick="test()" type="button" value="try">

<script>
var num1 = 1;
var num2 = 0;
var total;
function test(){
     two();
     total = num1 + num2;
     alert(total);
}
function two(){
    num2 = 2;
    return num2;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `$.fn` is jQuery's [prototype](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp) chain, you can share the jQuery object/instance's context (`this`)

```
$.fn.funcion01 = function () {
    this.section = $('#thissection').val();
}

$.fn.funcion02 = function () {
    // this.section is defined if you ran funcion01
}
```

> This allows any `var obj = $("#someID")` to have `.funcion01` and `.funcion02` and if you run `obj.funcion01()` first, then `obj.section` will be defined and accessible to anyone that has access to `obj`. It will also be inside `obj.funcion01()`

---

Or you can pollute some global namespace, like the `window`

```
$.fn.funcion01 = function () {
    var section = $('#thissection').val();
    window.funcion01Section = section;
}

$.fn.funcion02 = function () {
    var section = window.funcion01Section;
}
```